# Post link to Facebook page as page admin

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm trying to post a link to the wall of a Facebook page *as the page admin*, however it's not working correctly. It posts the link as me rather than as the page admin, and it shows up under "Recent Posts by Others" rather than the wall.

```
var client = new FacebookClient(post.Site.FacebookAccessToken);
dynamic result = client.Post("/" + pageId + "/feed", new {
    message = post.Message,
    link = post.Url
});
```

My access token has publish_stream and manage_pages permissions. The authorized Facebook account is an admin for the page. Is there some method for impersonating the page admin that I'm not doing correctly?

Comment: Are you using the Page access token or a user access token? it should be the former

Comment: I don't care what everyone else says about you, you're a genius. Feel free to post a response and I'll mark as answer.

Comment: Oh yes, he's a genius !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a Page [access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/) if you want the post to appear 'as the page' - if you use your user access token the behaviour depends on some settings in the page management interface of Facebook and may or may not post as the page depending on those settings.